# Get whole img tag Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Is there a way to get the whole img tag?
This is my code, but this only gives me the src. I want to get the whole img tag and put it in a string so i can use it when i load the page, the picture loads with it
HTML :

```
<img id="1" src="http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_2015_logo_detail.png"/>
```

Javascript :

```
var html = document.getElementById('1').src;
alert(html);
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why doe you want to get the html as string?

Comment: The reason why you want to do it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Is there a easier way to get the img in a string, like in whatts app with the emoji's

Comment: what? i never get whatsapp emojis as string ???

Comment: No but i want to do the same, but i don't know how to get images in a string. So i thought this would be the correct way. But i think is was wrong

Comment: what do you mean by getting images as string? Here you are asking how to whole img tag as a string, people answered correctly

Answer (score 2):

Don't ask for the `.src` property then and you'll get the entire element. From there, you can convert the element into a string by accessing its `outerHTML` property.

```js
// Get the element as a string
var elem = document.querySelector("img").outerHTML;

// For testing, show the type of content we now have (string) 
// followed by the content itself
console.log(typeof elem, elem);
```

```html
<img id="youtubeimg" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VK4ah66jBvE/0.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Ids are allowed to start with a number in HTML 5.

Comment: but he didnt mention HTML5

Comment: Unless otherwise stated, it's assumed that HTML is HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: 1** Following code solution is using Jquery.

Using Jquery, you need to select the Right Selector, If you are using the ID selector then you can make use of `$("#1")`; Then for selecting the complete tag, you can make use of the `outerHTML` property.

```js
var element = $("#1");
console.log(element.prop('outerHTML'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="1" src="http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_2015_logo_detail.png"/>
```

Comment: This code should select the `img` tag with ID `1`. Why the downvote ?

Comment: I didn't down vote but, your code returns a JQuery wrapped set reference, not a string of the node.

Comment: Thanks Scott, Original question was about getting the Img element.

Comment: I didn't down vote neither, but how he is not using jquery?

Comment: Question has not been edited. It did ask for a string.

Comment: Also, as JJ mentioned, ID can be Numeric as per HTML 5 specification.

Comment: I have updated the post as per the OP question, i misunderstood the OP.

Comment: @mplungjan `console.log(element[0])` produces a string because it's being written to the console, but `console.log(typeof element[0])` shows `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `outerHTML` instead of `src`:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('img1');
alert(wrapper.outerHTML);
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="https://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_2015_logo_detail.png"/>
```